# OptionsMenu display only first item in each list?

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

Here I have a basic OptionsMenu and a list with lists inside of it for my Menu options. What I need to do is display only the first item of the sub lists in the options menu but when that item is selected to pass the 2nd item in the sub list to a function.

Currently I can display all of the sub list and pass all of the sub list to a function. The main problem I am having is trying to display JUST the first item "ID 1" or "ID 2" in the drop down menu.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

def print_data(x):
    print(x[1])

example_list = [["ID 1", "Some data to pass later"], ["ID 2", "Some other data to pass later"]]
tkvar = tk.StringVar()
tkvar.set('Select ID')

sellection_menu = tk.OptionMenu(root, tkvar, *example_list, command=print_data)
sellection_menu.config(width=10, anchor='w')
sellection_menu.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This is what I get:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

As you can see in the 2nd image only the "ID 1" is displayed in the menu and the data for that ID is printed to console.

I cannot find any documentation or post abut this issue so it may not be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think about is this

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
```

do a for loop that takes the first index and that is the ID

```
sellection_menu = tk.OptionMenu(root, tkvar,
                            *[ID[0] for ID in example_list],
                            command=print_data)
```

search for the given index but this is slow and not so good if you are using a lot of data

```
def print_data(x):
    for l in example_list:
        if x == l[0]:
            print(l[1])
            break


example_list = [["ID 1", "Some data to pass later"], 
                ["ID 2", "Some other data to pass later"]]`
```

Comment: Ah perfect. That will do nicely. Thank you very much :D. Delete `tkvar.set(x)`. Its not helping anything here and it works fine without this line.

Comment: Converting the `example_list` into a dictionary to do the lookup may speed up (and simplify) the program.